# Is there anything wrong with gcc when compiling a nonthrowing pointing to a function which might throw?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, visual-c++, noexcept

I have read the book C++ Primer 5th ed. In section Exception Specifications and Pointers, Virtuals, and Copy Control, it says:

> That is, if we declare a pointer that has a nonthrowing exception specification, we can use that pointer only to point to similarly qualified
>   functions.

And I also refer to [noexcept specifier (since C++11)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec), there is also something similar:

> Pointers to non-throwing functions are implicitly convertible (since C++17)can be assigned (until C++17) to pointers to potentially-throwing functions, but not the other way around.

```
void ft(); // potentially-throwing
void (*fn)() noexcept = ft; // error
```

When I compile the sample snippet with `gcc version 5.4.0 20160609`, there is no error or warning.
But when I compile it with `Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.24215.1 for x86`, it complains that `error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'void (__cdecl *)(void)' to 'void (__cdecl *)(void) noexcept'`. It seems right behavior.

So I wonder is there something wrong with `gcc` compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this page](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html), the C++17 feature "Make exception specifications be part of the type system" is available starting from GCC 7.0.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this doesn't answer the question. The OP's code is invalid C++11 (see T.C's answer bellow for details). It's a GCC bug.

Comment: @zhenguoli It was pointed out to me that my answer is wrong. You should accept T.C.'s answer instead so I can delete this one

Answer (score 2):

GCC bug. This is not valid C++11/14 either. N3337 [[except.spec]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/except.spec), emphasis mine:

> If a virtual function has an *exception-specification*, all
>   declarations, including the definition, of any function that overrides
>   that virtual function in any derived class shall only allow exceptions
>   that are allowed by the *exception-specification* of the base class
>   virtual function. [ *Example:* ...  *— end example* ] **A similar
>   restriction applies to assignment to and initialization of pointers to
>   functions, pointers to member functions, and references to functions:
>   the target entity shall allow at least the exceptions allowed by the
>   source value in the assignment or initialization.**

This is what people mean when they say that pre-C++17 exception specification is a "shadow type system": they are not part of the actual type, but behave in several contexts (initialization, assignment, virtual overrides) as if they are.

Answer (score 1):

Historically, [exception specifiers have not been part of the type system](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#92):

> 92. Should ***exception-specifications*** be part of the type system?
>
> […]
>
> EWG determined that no action should be taken on this issue.

This is certainly a bit surprising.  It is not a loophole in the type system as such because the types are still checked at run time (resulting in abnormal translation if necessary).

However, this issue was resurrected in [P0012R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0012r1.html) and merged into the standard with [this commit](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/6e75f2d588a4b1b0c220eb8eec4b9ad8cb6107f3):

```
commit 6e75f2d588a4b1b0c220eb8eec4b9ad8cb6107f3
Author: Dawn Perchik <dperchik@embarcadero.com>
Date:   Thu Oct 29 12:11:02 2015 -0700

    P0012R1 Make exception specifications be part of the type system, version 5
```

So it's not in C++14, but will be in C++17.  Typically, there is some lag until compilers implement new language features.